# Gulp watch not recognised as function

Tags: gulp

This is a full gulp js file. Here `gulp-watch` is not used. So it's commented.

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    gulp.src(['app/*.js', 'app/shared/*/*.js','app/components/*/*.js'])
        .pipe(plumber({
            handleError: function(err) {
                console.log(err);
                this.emit('end');
            }
        }))
        // .pipe(watch(['app/*.js', 'app/shared/*/*.js','app/components/*/*.js']))
        .pipe(print(function(filepath) {
            return "MrGopal modified : " + filepath;
        }))
        .pipe(ngAnnotate())
        .pipe(concate('zaya.app.js'))
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: '.min'
        }))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/js'))
        .pipe(broswerSync.stream())
})
```

Browser sync TASK

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    broswerSync.init({
        notify: true,
        proxy: "http://localhost:8000"
    })
})

gulp.task('scripts-sync',['scripts'],broswerSync.reload)
gulp.task('html-sync',['html'],broswerSync.reload)
gulp.task('less-sync',['less'],broswerSync.reload)
```

WATCH TASK

```
gulp.watch(['app/*.js', 'app/shared/*/*.js', 'app/components/*/*.js'], ['scripts','scripts-sync']);
gulp.watch(['app/shared/*/*.html','app/components/*/*.html'], ['html','html-sync']);
gulp.watch(['app/shared/*/*.css','app/components/*/*.css'], ['less','less-sync']);
```

DEFAULT TASK

```
gulp.task('default', ['scripts', 'html', 'less', 'watch','browser-sync'])
```

While running gulp, it says watch is not a function. But same code works at my office. What could be wrong?

The error code :

```
[16:03:49] 'watch' errored after 244 μs
[16:03:49] TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Gulp.watch (/home/gopal/Documents/zaya-proto/zaya/zaya/static/node_modules/gulp/index.js:35:16)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/home/gopal/Documents/zaya-proto/zaya/zaya/static/gulpfile.js:96:10)
    at module.exports (/home/gopal/Documents/zaya-proto/zaya/zaya/static/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/home/gopal/Documents/zaya-proto/zaya/zaya/static/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/home/gopal/Documents/zaya-proto/zaya/zaya/static/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
    at /home/gopal/Documents/zaya-proto/zaya/zaya/static/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:279:18
    at finish (/home/gopal/Documents/zaya-proto/zaya/zaya/static/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:21:8)
    at module.exports (/home/gopal/Documents/zaya-proto/zaya/zaya/static/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:60:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/home/gopal/Documents/zaya-proto/zaya/zaya/static/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/home/gopal/Documents/zaya-proto/zaya/zaya/static/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
```

Comment: Are you using `gulp-watch`?

Comment: No. i didn't used gulp-watch